# Laravel policy for editing

Tags: php, laravel, policy

So I have created a policy and registered it in the AuthServicePRovider, but it always returns false. It is my first time working with policies so I am sure I am doing it wrong, but following a few examples, nothing has worked for me.

I am logged in with user that has an id of 1. I try to edit a label that has a user_id of 1, returns false, and also when trying to edit a label that has a user_id of 2. This last one works as expected, but f the user_id and label->user_id match, I should ave a form displayed. Instead, I get this each time:

```
This action is unauthorized.
```

Any ideas?

AuthServiceProvider: (Tried both but both don't work):

```
protected $policies = [
    'App\Label' => 'App\Policies\LabelPolicy'
];

And this one also did not do the trick:

protected $policies = [
    Label::class => LabelPolicy::class
];
```

LabelsController@edit:

```
public function edit(Label $label)
{
    // $this->authorize('edit', $label); // This also returns false

    if (auth()->user()->cannot('edit', $label)) {
        dd('NO'); // This is always shown
    }
}
```

LabelPolicy:

```
public function edit(Label $label)
{
    dd('test'); // This is never shown anywhere
    return auth()->user()->id === $label->user_id;
}
```

Comment: I the label model has a relation with the user model use it instead  of accessing the `user_id` directly: `return auth()->user()->id === $label->user->id;`

Comment: I think this error `This action is unauthorized.` is due to routing problems ! If you have a resource controller. Could you please add you routes !

Comment: Indeed, using a resource controller for the labels: Route::resource('labels', 'LabelsController');

Comment: I do have a relation, but return auth()->user()->id === $label->user->id; didn't work either. So I might have something else wrong somewhere, as it seems I've set up everything correctly, also now thanks to Mina's answer

Comment: So you when you access 'lables/edit/some_id' you get `This action is unauthorized.` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The policies expects actually two inputs, the first input is always the User class, the second input is the Model and defaults to the Model class. So in your case:

### LabelPolicy

```
public function edit(User $user, Label $label)
{
    return $user->id === $label->user_id;
}
```

### LabelsController@edit:

```
public function edit(Label $label)
{
    $this->authorize($label);
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, that was what I tried first, with the User $user in the policy, also didn't work for me

Comment: If the dd() in the Policy never runs, this is probably mapping issue in the AuthServiceProvider. Are you sure the Model and Policy class names are correct?

Comment: Correct including the namespace, and the namespace in the Policy file is correct as well.

Comment: And there we go. Cocky me thought I had it right, I even checked it a bunch of times. Ofcourse after checking it one last time, I saw I had a namespace wrong. Works fine now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

if your $this->authorize inside Controllers always returns false, then double check if your model and model policy namespace was imported in AuthServiceProvider and also your model has been imported into your controller.